# How to keep variable trailing zeroes both in display and storage of numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When a user enters a number with trailing zeros into Google Sheets, I want the number displayed in the sheet’s cell and the number retrieved via Apps Script to be identical to the number entered. The numbers being entered have a variable number of digits before and after the decimal, e.g. `1.00`,`11.00`, `1`, and `11.0`. All need to be displayed and retrieved as entered and as numbers.

The I only way I know how to resolve this is by formatting the value as a string, and then converting it to a number in Apps Script before further processing. I’m trying to avoid formatting numbers as strings to begin with though. Unless I'm missing something, Google Sheets makes this impossible.

How can I keep the variable number of trailing zeroes both in the display of the number and when the number is retrieved via `getValue()` in Apps Script? Is there way to do this without formatting as string?

Format options that I’ve tried:

- Automatic and `###` formats will display entry `1.00` as `1`.
- `####0.00` and `0.00` formats will display entry `1` as `1.00`.
- Scientific formatting will display `1` as `1.00E+00`.
- Plain text format. I have `=ISNUMBER(myRange)` as a custom data validation formula so it will reject any entry made as plain text. I would rather not drop this validation as these entries must be further processed as numbers. Therefore, I want to ensure that they're numbers upon entry.

For @Kos:

This can be reproduced by executing any of the formatting options that I outlined above. I didn't realize that this needs to be spelled out:

1. Open a Google Sheet.
2. Click the `Format` menu.
3. Hover over `Number`.
4. Click `Custom number format`.
5. Paste `####0.00` into the entry field.
6. Click `Apply`.
7. In the cell that you formatted, enter `1.0`. (Will display as `1.00`, which can be expected.)
8. In Google Apps Script run the following:

```
function testFormat() {

let sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(<your_sheet_id>).getSheetByName(<your_sheet_name>);
let formattedRange = sheet.getRange(<your_cell_row_number>,<your_cell_column_number>,1,1);

Logger.log(formattedRange.getValue())
}
```

The above will return `1.0` regardless of entering `1.0` or `1.00`.

Comment: What's steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue() on google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691425/difference-between-getvalue-and-getdisplayvalue-on-google-app-script)

Comment: I think plain text will give you what you desire

Comment: I mentioned that the entries need to be "displayed and retrieved ... as numbers," not text. @Kos I'm aware of the difference between these two already. The problem with `getDisplayValue()` is that it returns a string, not a number. I understand that I can convert this but it's not good practice to store/retrieve numbers as text to begin with. @Cooper Like I mentioned, I understand this can be handled with plain text. I'm interested to learn if I can handle this without using plain text as these values are numbers.

Comment: `The above will return 1.0 regardless of entering 1.0 or 1.00.` ok, and what do you need that for? Number is number, use it for calculations or whatever

Comment: Do you understand that number format is a string right?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533300/what-data-types-does-google-sheets-support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57428683/unexpected-output-values-are-coming/57429354#57429354